# The sequence is not correct when using insert into function in VBA

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

Got a question here, the code works nicely no error at all, but when I add record to access the sequence just got wrong. Please refer to the image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uncf4.png), the record of John Doe, the User_ID weirdly fall under user_name, user_IC fall to user_ID and also user_name fall to user_IC. Is there any error in my code? I have change the sequence after VALUES but still the same.

```
Try
            con.Open()
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [user biodata] VALUES('" & User_nameTextBox.Text & "','" & User_IDTextBox.Text & "','" & User_ICTextBox.Text & "','" & User_genderTextBox.Text & "','" & User_phoneTextBox.Text & "','" & User_stateTextBox.Text & "','" & User_pwTextBox.Text & "')", con)
            If (User_ICTextBox.Text = "" And User_nameTextBox.Text = "" And User_genderTextBox.Text = "" And User_phoneTextBox.Text = "" And User_stateTextBox.Text = "" And User_IDTextBox.Text = "" And User_pwTextBox.Text = "") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the details")
            Else
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Succerssfully Registered. You can login now!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
                Me.Close()
                Form1.Show()
                User_ICTextBox.Clear()
                User_nameTextBox.Clear()
                User_genderTextBox.Clear()
                User_phoneTextBox.Clear()
                User_stateTextBox.Clear()
                User_IDTextBox.Clear()
                User_pwTextBox.Clear()
            End If
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error")
            User_ICTextBox.Clear()
            User_nameTextBox.Clear()
            User_genderTextBox.Clear()
            User_phoneTextBox.Clear()
            User_stateTextBox.Clear()
            User_IDTextBox.Clear()
            User_pwTextBox.Clear()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either modify your code completely to parameters, or specify the order of the field names:

```
"INSERT INTO [user biodata] ([Field1], [Field2] .. [FieldN]) VALUES('" & User_nameTextBox.Text & "',' .."
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I figure it out! It should follow the sequence that shown in data source, not how you arrange in access, so the sequence will be correct. Thank you so much by the way!